# Difference between using getOrDefault() and elvis operator on a Map

Tags: kotlin

Could someone explain why these two lines act differently? activeGames is a MutableMap<String, Game>.

`val game = activeGames.getOrDefault(id, Game(id))`

`val game = activeGames[id]?:Game(id)`

For whatever reason, whenever I pass in the id key for a game that I know exists, calling getOrDefault always does the default behavior of creating a new game instead of grabbing the game from the map. But the line with the elvis operator works like I expect, and gets the existing game from the map.

I am instantiating activeGames with:

`val activeGames = mutableMapOf<String, Game>()`

Comment: I'm having a similar but intermittent problrm.  I bracketed it down to getDefault and even managed to step the debugger through it.  Debugger was giving a generic error.  I replaced with an elvis operator and problem seems to have cleared up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with the id you pass to `getOrDefault`
try debugging your code and throw an exception if `activeGames.containsKey(id)`
returns false.

if I reproduce your logic that you describe this what we expect to get
and I just test it and this is the outcome.

```
data class Game(val gameId: String)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val id = "bla"
    val activeGames = mapOf(id to Game(id))
    val game1 = activeGames.getOrDefault(id, Game(id))
    val game2 = activeGames[id] ?: Game(id)
    println("game1 : $game1")
    println("game2 : $game2")
}
```

**output:**

```
game1 : Game(gameId=bla)
game2 : Game(gameId=bla)
```